# Magento 2 Custom Grid data unable to save?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid

i have created a module **Demo_Bootstrapimages** grid using **silk software** in Magento 2 when saving the record from admin panel it wasn't able to save properly.

I have created the table.
[image]
whether anyone face this kind of issue? please help me.

[image]

Comment: Check whether your custom table is created properly or not

Comment: Yes, i have created table as shown in the  http://prntscr.com/ep1r6n

Comment: Can you check concol or error log when you try to save data? Or share the code of controller?